# Cassandra sstableloader gives "Stream failed" error

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

On a Debian machine, I have a single-node Cassandra 3.7 cluster to which I try to use sstableloader to import data from sstable files to a table ccp.srsdatabulk. I get a streaming error that I don't get past.

The sstableloader command and the sstable files are on the same machine as the Cassandra cluster (but I still need to enter the external IP address of the machine, using 127.0.0.1 doesnt't work).

I have a folder structure home/username/ftpupload/bulkimport/ccp/srsdatabulk, where the srsdatabulk contains the following files that I created with CQLSSTableWriter using the instructions from http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/using-the-cassandra-bulk-loader-updated

```
mb-1-big-CompressionInfo.db
mb-1-big-Data.db
mb-1-big-Digest.crc32
mb-1-big-Filter.db
mb-1-big-Index.db
mb-1-big-Statistics.db
mb-1-big-Summary.db
mb-1-big-TOC.txt
```

As you can see, the files are named "mb"-something by the CQLSSTableWriter, I don't know if they should contain the table name?

When I try to run sstableloader from the bin directory of Cassandra:

```
./sstableloader -d 123.456.789.0 -u theusername -pw thepassword -cph 1 /home/username/ftpupload/bulkimport/ccp/srsdatabulk/
```

It kind of starts streaming but immediately disconnects the stream and gives a error:

```
Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
Streaming relevant part of /home/username/ftpupload/bulkimport/ccp/srsdatabulk/mb-1-big-Data.db to [/123.456.789.0]
progress: [/123.456.789.0]0:1/1 100% total: 100% 157.155KiB/s (avg: 157.155KiB/s)
progress: [/123.456.789.0]0:1/1 100% total: 100% 0.000KiB/s (avg: 156.364KiB/s)
progress: [/123.456.789.0]0:1/1 100% total: 100% 0.000KiB/s (avg: 155.610KiB/s)
progress: [/123.456.789.0]0:1/1 100% total: 100% 0.000KiB/s (avg: 154.892KiB/s)
ERROR 15:32:51 [Stream #3682f870-d813-11e6-b238-db523103ddb3] Remote peer 123.456.789.0 failed stream session.
progress: [/123.456.789.0]0:1/1 100% total: 100% 0.000KiB/s (avg: 153.550KiB/s)
WARN  15:32:51 [Stream #3682f870-d813-11e6-b238-db523103ddb3] Stream failed
Streaming to the following hosts failed:
[/123.456.789.0]
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:99)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:49)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:85)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1310)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:215)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:191)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:430)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.sessionFailed(StreamSession.java:650)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.messageReceived(StreamSession.java:490)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:274)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:115)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:49)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:99)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:85)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1310)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:215)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:191)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:430)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.sessionFailed(StreamSession.java:650)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.messageReceived(StreamSession.java:490)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:274)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Did you check cassandra's `system.log` for errors? I was experiencing the exact same thing and the system log showed a much clearer error.

Comment: @maccer did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Hi I meet the same issue, did you have a solution or the root cause?